# Redmine Office 365 Email Configuration Error

Tags: redmine

This is the config/configuration.yml file I use:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.office365.com" 
      port: 587
      domain: "smtp.office365.com" 
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "xxx@xxx" 
      password: "xxx"
```

when I send test mail in Redmine, it results to this error:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:649:in `commit'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:484:in `[]='
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:116:in `set_cookie'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:403:in `commit_session'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/passenger-6.0.4/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/passenger-6.0.4/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:157:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
```

What can I do to prevent this problem?